# VB6 window over .NET window

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

I have function in VB6 which shows window (VB6 window). I'm calling this function from .NET window. VB6 window appears correctly, it's on the top and is active. I can write something in it, change focus to other control (using tab key), but when I click on this window (VB6) then I'm moved to .NET window (VB6 window goes back).

What could be wrong? I've tried to set parent/owner/focus using WinApi but with no results.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing like an "VB6 window" or "NET window" - all of these are native windows with different properties.

If your focus gets stolen by another window your messageqeue or window-inheritance isnt set up correctly - its good practice to have one main window and X child-windows, you can add z-order to them if you want that many windows ... win32-GIMP uses that, it just doesnt look right but thats just my 2 cents.

You can pass the HWND of your main window via parameter, this doc should give you some insight on the appropriate parameter-list : [CreateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
especially WS_CHILD will be necessary : [Window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And if you want a fire-and-forget solution : switch to dialogs : [DialogBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
--> this will create a modal dialog, which pretty much solves all of your problems in one step ... its a somewhat special window, though - out-of-the-box functionality comes at its price ...